# Linq with group by having count

Tags: linq, count, group-by, having

how do I write this query in linq (vb.net)?

```
 select B.Name
 from Company B
 group by B.Name
 having COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333265/having-and-conditional-count-in-linq-query

Answer (score 373, accepted):

Like this:

```
from c in db.Company
group c by c.Name into grp
where grp.Count() > 1
select grp.Key
```

Or, using the method syntax:

```
Company
    .GroupBy(c => c.Name)
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
    .Select(grp => grp.Key);
```

Answer (score 7):

For anyone looking to do this in vb (as I was and couldn't find anything)

```
From c In db.Company 
Select c.Name Group By Name Into Group 
Where Group.Count > 1
```

Comment: I find it hard to understand why the `Group By` is after the `Select` clause in VB.

Answer (score -2):

Below solution may help you.

```
var unmanagedDownloadcountwithfilter = from count in unmanagedDownloadCount.Where(d =>d.downloaddate >= startDate && d.downloaddate <= endDate)
group count by count.unmanagedassetregistryid into grouped
where grouped.Count() > request.Download
select new
{
   UnmanagedAssetRegistryID = grouped.Key,
   Count = grouped.Count()
};
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?