# How to determine duplicates in a collection of ints?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, duplicates

Let's say I've got the following values in a collection of integers:

```
{1,3,4,5,5,6,7,7}
```

The result I'd expect is `{5,7}`.

How can I do that? Maybe using LINQ?

**EDIT:** The input collection is unsorted, so the algorithm should not rely on duplicates being consecutive. Also, whether the resulting duplicate collection is sorted or not doesn't matter.

Comment: if the array is unsorted go for the hashset, else you can just compare each element with the next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with built-in functionality with LINQ, and it works on LINQ providers like LINQ to SQL and EF and NHibernate:

```
var dups = collection.GroupBy(x => x)
                     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                     .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OnlyDupes<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var seen = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        // HashSet<T>.Add returns: true if the element is added to the
        // HashSet<T> object; false if the element is already present.
        if (!seen.Add(item)) yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't play nice with LINQ providers like LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @Jason: good to know. We don't use L2S in our shop so I'm not terribly familiar with its limitations.

Comment: That's fine. It won't play nice with ANY LINQ providers that work on a database; it will execute in memory instead of on the database.

Comment: @Jason: obvious once pointed out :) Based on some other comments I'm now wondering if he wants them in order found or even "back to back dupes only".

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7 };
var duplicates =  list.GroupBy(x => x)
                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                      .Select(g => g.Key)
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
int[] listOfItems = new[] { 4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 4, 3 };
var duplicates = listOfItems
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
foreach (var d in duplicates)
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

from [Finding Duplicates Using LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/08/19/find-duplicates-using-linq.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new List<int>(){1,3,4,5,5,6,7,7};

var query = ( from i in list
               group i by i into g
               where g.Count() > 1
               select g.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: The `Distinct` is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HashSet<T>` if you are on .NET 3.5, or [Iesi.Collections](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sets.aspx) (NHibernate uses this)

Comment: It doesn't play nice with LINQ providers like LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

[Linq with group by having count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078736/linq-with-group-by-having-count) will show you how to do a LINQ group by having count > 1

In your specific instance:

```
var x = from i in new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 3 }
    group i by i into grp
    where grp.Count() > 1
    select grp.Key;
```