# Search rows with duplicate value in datatable

Tags: c#

I have this datatable (RadkyData):

```
Name     EAN   PRICE
ITEM1   12345   10
ITEM2   5558    55
ITEM3   12345   44
```

I need to search rows with duplicate value EAN.? (a list of all EAN that are duplicate)
I have this code:

```
var polozkySum = RadkyData.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(r => new
                    {
                        c2 = r.Field<string>("EAN")
                    })
                    .GroupBy(g => new { g.c2 })
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        col2 = x.Key.c2
                    });
```

Have you any ideas please?

Comment: see the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078736/linq-with-group-by-having-count. That's what you need.

Comment: what should be the result? a list of all EAN that are duplicate or the rows itself?

Comment: @Mat a list of Ean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rowsWithDupEAN = RadkyData.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("EAN"))
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

If you don't want the rows but only this column values(as mentioned in a comment):

```
var dupEanList = RadkyData.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("EAN"))
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use LINQ to DataTable.

```
 var result = Radkydata.AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("EAN"))
             .Select(g => g.First())
             .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: this is not giving the list of *duplicates*