# Select users with similar name, but different password

Tags: c#, linq

I need a function which returns a filtered list of distinct users with different usernames. I want to exclude the users who have similar usernames, but with different passwords.

Input
user1 ("Jim", 1111)
user2 ("Jim", 3333)
user3 ("Bill", 2222)
user4 ("Mike", 2222)

Output
user3 ("Bill", 2222)
user4 ("Mike", 2222)

```
private IEnumerable<User> GetCorrectUsers(IEnumerable<User> userList)
{
   IEnumerable<User> filtered= userList.GroupBy(user => user.UserName)
      .Select(g => g.???)
      .Where(p => p.Password).Distinct().Count() > 1;
   return filtered;
}
```

One step is missing.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078736/linq-with-group-by-having-count

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Count() = 1` ?

Comment: @sagi technically `Count() == 1` but I'm with ya... ;)

Comment: If you ever get to storing real passwords, please remember to hash and salt them according to best practices at the time you implement such code.

Comment: I am just thinking about interesting application design - password will be the key to determine a user.

Comment: What if two distinct users actually have the same password?

Comment: The password is just an example, I did not want to write the actual property. I don't care about different user's having similar passwords.

Comment: What if we have 3 users as {Name = "Jim", Password = 1111}, {Name = "Jim", Password = 1111}, {Name = "Jim", Password = 2222}. Should we exclude all of them or select the one with '2222' password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from comment of Caius Jard the solution can be:

```
var filtered = users.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Where(g => g.Select(grElem => grElem.Password).Distinct().Count() == 1).Select(x => x.First())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: You haven't considered his password condition at all, He needs to omit users who have similar usernames  with different passwords.

Comment: Thanks, it looks okay. I'll test it. All of the users with same name, but different password must be excluded.