# How to combine select and group by clause with conditional where in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'am learning ASP.Net MVC with SQL Server Database and got stuck in Linq operation query. Can anyone help me to convert this SQL query to Linq, please ?

```
SELECT ShipName, COUNT(*) AS ShipValues
FROM Invoinces GROUP BY ShipName HAVING COUNT(*) > 30
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078736/linq-with-group-by-having-count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var result = Invoinces.GroupBy(x => x.ShipName)
                      .Where(y => y.Count() > 30)
                      .Select(o => new {ShipName = o.ShipName, Count = o.Count()});
```