# LINQ get column based on another column having count >1

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am struggling to get column A value by querying a column B for duplicates from database with Entity Framework Core. Example:

```
Column A | Column B
--------------------
A        | 1
B        | 1 
C        | 2 
D        | 2 
E        | 3
```

I should get output:

```
A,B,C,D
```

Which I plan to use to populate a drop down list.

I’ve tried:

```
Options = _context.table.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(s => new{ s.columnA,s.columnB)
.Where(o => o.columnB.Count() > 1)
.Select(o => new SelectListItem
{
   Value = o.Key.columnA,
   Text = o.Key.columnB
}.ToList()
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Either you use o.columnB.Count() > 1 or o.columnB > 1, you can not get A, B, C, D as output.. You should group data on columnB and then check count of group elements.`Options = _context.table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(s => s.columnB).Where(o => o.Count() > 1).Select(o => new SelectListItem
{
   Value = o.columnA,
   Text = o.columnB
}.ToList()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq with group by having count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078736/linq-with-group-by-having-count)

Comment: @DragandDrop no, that solution only display for the column I am checking for duplicates (in this case, columnB). I need to display Column A items that has duplicates in column B.

Comment: As Karan said, since you want to get the duplicates records based on the columnB, the GroupBy statement should like this `.GroupBy(s=>s.columnB)`, Then, you could use the SelectMany method to find the sub items, `Options  = context.table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(s => s.columnB).Where(o => o.Count() > 1).SelectMany(o => o).Select(d => new SelectListItem(){  Text = d.columnA,  Value = d.columnB.ToString() }).ToList();`

Comment: Right, but `SelectMany()` uses too much memory. I've got quite a big database.

Comment: @AaronYong `SelectMany` is not using much memory because it just flattens the found duplicates only. Too much memory usage is from client side evaluation of `GroupBy` (after `AsEnumerable()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to count on `columnB` only then you should be using `.GroupBy(s => s.columnB)`. Update your `Where` & `Select` like below.

**Note** Need to use `SelectMany` wiht `Select` inside it because if we use `Select` instead of `SelectMany` it will return `List<List<SelectListItem>>`. `SelectMany` will flatten it and return `List<SelectListItem>`.

```
Options = _context.table.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(s => s.columnB)
            .Where(o => o.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(o => o.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
               Value = x.columnA,
               Text = x.columnB
            }))
            .ToList();
```

**Detail Explanation** [Credits to @Flater from helpful comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717320/linq-get-column-based-on-another-column-having-count-1/63717492?noredirect=1#comment112683292_63717492)
The lambda in `GroupBy` is essentially the "group identifier". In the question, each group is defined by the combined uniqueness of columns A *and* B. But as per described into question it needs to combine things based on column B alone, with the goal to specifically group things *regardless* of what column A contains, so column A should **not** be included in the group's identifier, since the query should not make a new group when encountering a different column A value.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I think it can benefit from a small elaboration on why the `GroupBy` needed to be changed: the lambda in `GroupBy` is essentially the "group identifier". In the question, each group is defined by the combined uniqueness of columns A _and_ B. But OP wants to combine things based on column B alone, with the goal to specifically group things _regardless_ of what column A contains, so column A should not be included in the group's identifier, since the query should **not** make a new group when encountering a different column A value.

Comment: @Flater, thanks for your helpful comment. I have updated answer as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

So you have combinations of [ColumnA, ColumnB], and if you want all values of ColumnA where there is more than one ColumnB.

My advice would be to convert your [ColumnA, ColumnB] into groups of "ColumnB, with all ColumnA that have this ColumnB. Then keep only the Groups that have more than one ColumnA.

So in your example:

- 1 with values A, B
- 2 with values C, D
- 3 with value E

Throw away group 3 because it has only one element, and flatten the result.

We use the [overload of GroupBy that has an elementSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__). The elementSelector will select columnA as elements.

```
var combinationsColumnAColumnB = ...
var result = combinationsColumnB.GroupBy(
     // parameter keySelector: make groups with same ColumnB
     combination => combination.ColumnB,

    // parameter elementselector: put only the ColumnA in each group
    combination => combination.ColumnA)

    // result: groups of columnB with all columnA that belong to this columnB
    // keep only those groups that have more than one element
    .Where(group => group.Skip(1).Any()

    // and flatten the result:
    .SelectMany(group => group);
```

If you have combinations like:

```
A   1
A   2
B   1
C   2
```

You will get element A twice. If you don't want that, add a `Distinct()`