# How can I find if a part of a key (of a grouping) appears more than once in a list?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I want to find out which eprt_id appears twice. (Which in this case is: 20463)

```
Eprt_id: 21487 Perceel: Test
               subject: Apples
 
Eprt_id: 21696 Perceel: Test2
               subject: Oranges

Eprt_id: 21822 Perceel: Test3
               subject: Pears

Eprt_id: 23485 Perceel: Test4
               subject: Lemons

Eprt_id: 24238 Perceel: Test55
               subject: Watermelons
               subject: Oranges

Eprt_id: 20463 Perceel: Test56
               subject: Apples
               subject: Pears

Eprt_id: 20463 Perceel: Test57
               subject: Apples
               subject: Pears
```

This list is obviously a group on Eprt_id and Perceel.

But how can I write a decent linq statement that gives me the result (in this case) 20463 occurs more than once?

I got this list as follows:

```
var nextGroupedWorklist = from r in SubtractBSNlessFromWerklijst
                where r.Eprt_id.HasValue &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Subject_id) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Perceel_id) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Hermes_dossier_nr) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Gogis_perceel_nr)
                group r by new { r.Eprt_id, r.Gogis_perceel_nr };
```

I thought a simple count would do. But it obviously returns a count of the elements of the group.

I found a way to get 20463. But is this the best way?

```
 var solution = from r in nextGroupedWorklist
    group r by new { r.Key.Eprt_id }
    into grp
    where grp.Count() > 1
    select grp;
```

Secondly is there a clever way to check if both subjects are the same? (As they are in the example) Both 20463 eprt_id's contain the subject: Apples and Pears.
This an example list (as you can see 20463 each has two subjects that are the same in the 2 different Perceel columns) So that would be what I want to check. If they are both the same. I may proceed processing 20463. Otherwise not.:

```
 Eprt_id: 20229 Perceel: WPK02L1072G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.255545276 
 Eprt_id: 20267 Perceel: WPK02L1051G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.255545276 
 Eprt_id: 20463 Perceel: ASD31AL2317G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.170412796
 Eprt_id: 20463 Perceel: ASD31AL2317G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.455686300
 Eprt_id: 20463 Perceel: ASD31AL3076G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.170412796
 Eprt_id: 20463 Perceel: ASD31AL3076G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.455686300
 Eprt_id: 20524 Perceel: ASD31AL952G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.170348494 
 Eprt_id: 20524 Perceel: ASD31AL952G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.171028089 
 Eprt_id: 20939 Perceel: WPK02L260G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.171510661 
 Eprt_id: 20939 Perceel: WPK02L260G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.171510669 
 Eprt_id: 20944 Perceel: WPK02L6672G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.171510661
 Eprt_id: 20944 Perceel: WPK02L6672G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.171510669 
 Eprt_id: 21487 Perceel: WPK02L2503G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.170459916 
 Eprt_id: 21696 Perceel: ASD02A7343A61 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.171440573
 Eprt_id: 21822 Perceel: WPK02L1602G0 subject: NL.KAD.Persoon.459669099
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078736/linq-with-group-by-having-count

Comment: Please post the full type definition of `SubtractBSNlessFromWerklijst`. How is `subject` declared?

Comment: Do you need the whole grouping as well as knowing if part of the grouping repeats?

Comment: Yes indeed. So first I'm going to get the grouping withouth double for futher processing. And find out which are double so I can do some checks. To see if the Eprt_id is allowed to be processed.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<(int eprt, int count)> duplicates = SubtractBSNlessFromWerklijst
    .Where( r => r.Eprt_id.HasValue )
    .GroupBy( r => r.Eprt_id.Value )
    .Where( grp => grp.Count() > 1 )
    .Select( grp => ( eprt: grp.Key, count: grp.Count() ) )
    .ToList();
```

This will give you this output:

```
[
    ( eprt: 20463, count: 2 )
]
```

> Secondly is there a clever way to check if both subjects are the same?

We can't help you there because you haven't posted the definition of whatever type holds `subject`. Your example input data does not explain how the object-graph is structured.