# How to use having ,group by and distinct in linq or lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I need to convert the follwing query into **linq** or **lambda** expression

```
 SELECT count(Hid.HouseholdID) FROM
 (SELECT HouseholdID FROM tblTmpJoinAll 
 WHERE loyal = 1 Group By HouseholdId 
 HAVING Count(distinct BasketID)>1) as Hid;
```

So Far I have tried

```
lst.Where(f => f.Flybuys == true)
.GroupBy(h=>h.HouseholdID)
//.Where(x=>x.)// don't know what to right here
.Select(h => h.Key).Count();
```

Comment: Maybe this question can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333265/having-and-conditional-count-in-linq-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this code works.

```
lst.Where(f => f.Flybuys) // you don't need == true here
   .GroupBy(f => f.HouseholdID)
   .Where(f => f.GroupBy(i => i.BasketID).Count() > 1)
   .Count();
```

Comment: @MarcelB: `GroupBy(i => i.BasketID)` is the `Distinct` you want

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. i'll delete my other comment in a minute